# Accessing data in git bare repo

Tags: git

I've set up a remote server that I want to push git commits to. I've set it up with `git init --bare` based on advice, but noticed it doesn't have the files there (working tree) after content is pushed there. AKA. if I have a file called `something.txt` and add and commit it to a local repo, then push to the remote repo, it will record my commit but I can't actually see `something.txt` on the remote filesystem.

The problem is that I actually want to manipulate the file remotely via a hook. AKA. once I push to any branch, an "update" hook will read a file in the repo and send it to another program.

At the moment, I can print the file list remotely via `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` but I'm not yet sure how to view individual files or if I should even be doing it this way (doesn't seem like it's designed this way).

If I create the remote repo without `--bare`, then I get an error when trying to push due to lack of working tree.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can also print the file with command line tools, but is that really what you want? You can simply create a local checkout (`git clone $path-to-bare-repository $somewhere`).

If you really only care about that one file, have a look at `git cat-file`, e.g.

```
git cat-file -p $ID_FROM_LS_TREE
```

As a one-liner:

```
git cat-file -p $(git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD | grep something.txt | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: I primarily just want to access the file from within a git hook file, so I'll see if this works.

Comment: In that case you might need to replace HEAD with your revision, i.e. one of the parameters that is being passed into the hook (`$1`, `$2` or `$3`). I'm not sure which one though.